# How to process Callback from API POST NodeJS

Tags: node.js, angular, angularjs, api, callback

I am using this API Function
https://developers.cryptoapis.io/technical-documentation/wallet-as-a-service/transactions/create-coins-transaction-from-address-for-whole-amount

And a NodeJS back end with an Angular Front end.

I cannot figure out how the Callback in that functions POST works, It requires a domain setup and then for a JS function to take the post in but I cannot figure out how to do that.

Could someone please advise how to work with an API callback function like that

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you would need a route on your NodeJS server that this service ( cryptoAPI ) could call - so like (needs to be HTTPS) https://yourDomainTheApiIsHostedOn.com/callBack

The documentation does say it will only fire when the create coins function is called. The call back URL also will have some info so you can verify the HTTP traffic is really from them

> The callbackSecretKey can only be generated by the customer. It is used to create a unique hash string in the x-signature response header in the callback request sent from Crypto APIs 2.0 when the event occurs.

The domain verification is basically a process for cryptoAPI to ensure that you own that domain which is hosting your API

Documentation is here:

https://developers.cryptoapis.io/technical-documentation/general-information/callbacks#callback-security

Comment: So I would need to host my application to do this

Comment: If you want to get the callback response yes, you will need a valid domain name that the crypto service could verify most likely by using a DNS TXT record or CNAME